# "nointerpolation" hlsl specifier on dx9 and ps3_0

Tags: render, interpolation, hlsl, directx-9

Problem:
different results of indentical shaders on `dx9` and `dx11`. after pix-debugging it, i found that it interpolates values. flat shade mode fixes that but can't be used.

```
nointerpolation float flStart : COLOR1;
nointerpolation float flEnd : COLOR2;
```

Reason:
seems like `ps3_0` just ignore the `nointerpolation` specifier when `ps4_0` and higher doesn't

Question:
is it bug of dx9 or ps3_0? is there any other possible ways to not interpolate them through vs?

Comment: Do these values need to be per vertex or can you put them into a constant buffer?

Comment: only per vertex, also i know that i can/should force same values for all vertices in a triangle, but it would be more costly so i curious in ways to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

Shader Model 3.0 did not support interpolation qualifiers. In Shader Model 4.0, the interpolation mode is specified as an additional qualifier in the [`dcl_input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dcl-input) instruction, whereas the `dcl_texcoord` and `dcl_color` instructions part of Shader Model 3.0 do not take such a qualifier.

It is probably a mistake that the compiler is not issuing a diagnostic for this.